# Weirtd shading artefact?

Tags: shadows, matcaps

I have this weird (dark) shading (MatCap) on my model. I wonder what is wrong. The face normals seem to be correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: trigons and ngons problem: https://www.creativeshrimp.com/ngons-tutorial.html and probably you have some "non-planar surfaces"

Comment: Mh when I triangulate my model the problem still exists. How do I check for "non planar surfaces"?!

Comment: check these tools: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/cleanup.html